# How Submit or Log in Button Clicked in case of cURL

Tags: php, html, http, post, curl

In cURL, i Checked many examples of remotely log in into facebook and twitter but when we use cURL and run cURL function with id and pass post field then how that log in button clicked automatically.

For try i made a simple code but it is not working. Submit button is not clicked. When it is clicked, i should see all the entered data.

I can't Understand  how that log in button clicked.

When we assign variables to form and submit or Log in button clicked using cURL but how ?

I have two files. First is HTML and second is php file.

I want to create a simple cURL function that can insert data in to HTML form and then on show me a result of entered data.

**HTMl File:**

```
<form id="formcss"action="curl.php" method="POST">
             Enter Your name:
    <input type="text" name="aname"/><br/><br/>
    Enter your Mobile:
    <input type="text" name="amobile"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP File:**

```
    <?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"url/form.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "ename=tyrtyj&emobile=ytubtyu&sum=submit");
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
?>
```

**Third File (curl.php):**

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl needs to be configured to send a POST request to http://curl.php and not url/form.html.  Your web server will respond to GET requests for form.html, but will not handle a POST request to that URI, which is what your code tries to do.  Pointing curl to curl.php will make the same request a browser would once the form submit button is clicked.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"curl.php");
```

Comment: Solved thanks. Here we use "aname" and "amobile" to insert data. but what if any site doesn't have any "name" field in <input> element ?